# Momentjs format moment object and keep offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a momentjs object that hold a datetime with an offset. This moment object was created from its string representation:

```
var x = moment("2017-02-08T04:11:52+6:00")
```

After working with the object, I would like to get the same textual representation from the moment object.

I get the following results when trying to format the object:

- `x.format()`  => `"2017-02-08T04:11:52+14:00"`
- `moment.parseZone(x).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")`  => `"2017-02-07T14:11:52+00:00"`

How can I format my moment object such that I have the exact same representation again?

Comment: You'd think this use case would be covered by [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), but it sure doesn't look like it from the docs. Not very impressive.

Comment: `x.format()` gives me (moment `2.17.1`, tz `Europe/Rome`) `Invalid date` and _Deprecation warning_. I fear that the problem is `+6:00` instead of `+06:00` (2 digit) for offset in your input string

Comment: Gives invalid date on momentjs website. Can you confirm once ?

Comment: Just get a result as close as possible and fix it yourself later with string manipulation and a little bit of regex.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner - that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

- Your input is nonstandard because you've specified the offset as `+6:00`.  The ISO8601 format requires two digits in both hours and minutes offset.  (It shouold be `+06:00`.  For the rest of this answer, I'll assume that's a typo.)
- You're losing the original offset when you create the moment, because you are adjusting to the local time zone by calling `moment(...)`.  Therefore it doesn't exist in `x`, at least not in a way you can retrieve it.
- In general, `parseZone` should be passed a string, not a `Moment` object.
- You certainly can format as you asked, as long as you have parsed correctly to begin with.  You don't even need to specify a format string, as the one you're looking for is the default.

  ```
  var str1 = "2017-02-08T04:11:52+06:00";
  var mom = moment.parseZone(str1);
  var str2 = mom.format();  // "2017-02-08T04:11:52+06:00"
  ```